# connecting facebook test page to instagram account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, account, facebook-test-users

i'm developing a website that enables user to see and manage his Instagram posts and comments.i want to get advanced permissions by app review of Facebook. i have created a Facebook app with some test users. then i created test page's for them. but the problem is
i can't connect Facebook test page to Instagram business account . it gives me this error:

> sorry , an unknown error occurred , please try again.
> [image]

what should i do to connect Facebook test page to Instagram business account?

Comment: AFAIK, test users and the pages they create, can not interact with anything "real." Try this with a real user account that has a role in your app, and a real page created through that account.

Comment: hmm, seems right. but i'm afraid that Facebook reject my app review request.is there any kind of instagram test account like facebook test users to make us be able to connect test page to instagram test account?

Comment: You should not need app review, as long as you are testing with users that have a role in the app.

Comment: @Mond666 Did you resolve this issue? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: hi @Mond666 any resolution to this?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu nope , unfortunately even facebook support didn't gave me a solution . we just created a fake account and connected to our facebook and sent its information to facebook reviewer

Comment: @Mond666 They were very clear fake accounts would get your submission thrown out

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Have you found a solution? facing same issue reviewer is unable to test our app with fake account of facebook and insta. Test account is not connecting with instagram

Comment: unfortunately no , I couldn't connect them together I was only able to do this with my real account , so i gave my real account's information to reviewer and they said it's ok.